# UIWebView : Load percentage information

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I need to get information on loaded data percentage when UIWebView loads page.

I know that UIWebView does not provide corresponding API.

I would like to know is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use an external framework ([ASIHTTP](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), [AFNetworking](https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking)) that gives you some progress information to get the data, then load it into the UIWebView using [`– loadHTMLString:baseURL:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/loadHTMLString%3abaseURL%3a).

ASIHTTP, although not actively developed anymore, has a very nice class for your case:

> ASIWebPageRequest - download complete webpages, including external resources like images and stylesheets. Pages of any size can be indefinitely cached, and displayed in a UIWebview / WebView even when you have no network connection.